# Uniqueness of a nonlinear PDE

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I have a nonlinear PDE inside with a domain of the unit ball:
$$\begin{cases}
\Delta u = u^3 &\text{in} \ \ B(x,1) \\
u =0 &\text{on} \ \ \partial B(x,1)
\end{cases}
$$
I am asked to show uniqueness of this problem. Up to this point, I have only shown uniqueness and existence for linear PDE, not nonlinear PDE. Usually, the proof is as easy as multiplying by $u$, applying the divergence theorem, and the identity $D(uDu) = u\Delta u + |Du|^2$. However, since the PDE is nonlinear, this does not work. It would be great if someone could help me through this, or provide a reference to aid me.

Comment: If you multiply by $u$ and integrate (using the boundary condition to discard the boundary term) we get $\int[(\nabla u)^2 + u^4]{\rm d}V = 0$ and the integrand is positive.

Comment: @Winther But, that doesn’t proof anything, does it?

Comment: A simpler example: $\int_0^1 |f(x)|^2{\rm d}x = 0$ then what can we say of $f$?

Comment: @Winther Then, the area under $f^2$ on $[0,1]$ is zero.

Comment: Yes, so $f(x) = \ldots$? Think about it, that's all you need to solve it!

Comment: $f(x) \equiv 0$ s.t $x\in [0,1]$

Comment: @Winther It means that the n-dimensional Lebesgue measure of $(\nabla u)^2 + u^4$ is identically zero for $x\in B(x,1)$. But, that doesn’t tell us anything because that is just an implicit statement of the problem.

Comment: Oh, wait the integrand it positive implying that $u\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that the standard method does not work as it relies on linearity, but the same *technique* can be applied. Mutiplying the PDE by $u$ and integrating over $B(x,1)$ using $-u\Delta u = |\nabla u|^2 - \nabla\cdot(u\nabla u)$ and applying the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) to the last term gives us
$$u^4 - u\Delta u  = 0 \implies \underbrace{\int [u^4 + |\nabla u|^2]{\rm d}V}_{>0~\text{if $u\not\equiv 0$ since integrand is positive}} - \underbrace{\int u\nabla u\cdot {\rm d}S}_{\text{zero since}~u =0~\text{on boundary}} = 0$$

The only way this can hold true is if $u^4 + |\nabla u|^2 \equiv 0$ so $u \equiv 0$. It's also easy to check that this is indeed a solution to the problem.